# How can I perform a complete backup on Windows 7 without using the optical drive?

Tags: windows-7, backup, external-hard-drive, dell-inspiron, optical-drive

I have dell Inspiron N5050 laptop with the optical drive not being detected in My computer and also doesn't open on clicking the button to open.So the optical drive not opening and not being detected in My computer how can I perform a Full backup on the computer.

In order to get my laptop serviced I need to have a backup and with the above scenario I cannot think of which way to take a backup.I asked the technican and he suggested me to use a Sata case but the problem there is opening the laptop and locating the hard disk to which I don't have any Idea about.

I am thinking to the use of an portable Optical drive where the problem is with the right DVD to be used(DVD-R or DVD-RW) and If a portable hard drive is used then how much should the hard drive capacity and I would not be able to use Dell DVD which was provided for my laptop.

Its my first time performing a backup and I want to how can I backup without using the Dell full backup and recovery which is a premium

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) booted from [flash/hard drive](http://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php). Then you may [backup the whole disk to you portable hard drive](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image)...